# How to replace a dynamic value in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I replace dynamic value in `javascript/jquery`?

I have a string like this `myURL = http://www.demo.com?a=1&sp=2&c=3`; I want to replace `sp=2` with string like 'str=3'. The value of `'sp'` can change like `3,4,5`, etc.

I am using replace function of jQuery, but I am not sure how can I replace the dynamic value of `'sp'`

```
myURL.replace("sp=2", "str=3");
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using regex:

```
var myURL = "http://www.demo.com?a=1&sp=2&c=3";
var replacementNum = 123;

myURL = myURL.replace(/sp=\d+/g, 'sp=' + replacementNum);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7tjo2vut/)

The code above will replace `sp=` parameter with any number to the given replacement number. It is useful when you **don't know** `sp` paramenter value.

```js
var myURL = "http://www.demo.com?a=1&sp=2&c=3";
var replacementNum = 123;

myURL = myURL.replace(/sp=\d+/g, 'sp=' + replacementNum);
console.log(myURL);
```

Comment: @Rahul glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign it back to myURL

```
myURL = myURL.replace("sp=2", "str=3");
```

`replace` will return a value, it won't change the `myURL` value on its own.